# How to extract specific data from a textfile and then display it (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, text-files, jtextfield

I have a set of data that is displayed in this format:

```
total question,Hint count,Right question Count
```

These are integers which are separated by a ':'.

```
"01:02:03"
```

How can I read the text-file so that it picks out the '02' from the data and displays it?

I have written a basic program that only reads the text-file and displays it in a jTextField but I am finding it difficult to get information to help me do this.

In the end if I had these set of data,

```
number1"10:07:03"
number2"10:03:08"
number3"10:06:05"
number4"10:02:10"
```

I will extract 07, 03, 06, 02 from the data respectively.

Any input will be good and if anyone has on-line resources and tutorials, I will also be happy to have a look for myself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method and then on the String representing your line use  [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with the ":" delimiter.
Then it should be trivial for you to work out...

(If you never heard of bufferedreader please read the class description in the first link I provided.)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use the string manipulation methods in [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). In particular check out [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) using `:` as a delimiter.

You could also look into using more advanced regex's, see [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information. However, in this case, `split` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The example of using `readLine` and `split`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("yourFile.txt")));

String text;
while((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] parts = text.split(":");
    // now `parts` array will contain your data
}
```